# My Akonadi server keeps crashing on startup. How do I fix this?

Tags: mysql, 15.10, akonadi

I am trying to make KPIM work on my kubuntu (Wiley) machine.  When I try to start akonadi (the db server) it tells me it is not registered with dbus and fails to start -- heres the output of the command

```
tim@tim-desktop:~$ akonadictl start
Starting Akonadi Server... 
   done. 
tim@tim-desktop:~$ Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
search paths:  ("/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/sbin", "/bin", "/usr/games", "/usr/local/games", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/libexec", "/usr/libexec", "/opt/mysql/libexec", "/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin", "/opt/mysql/sbin") 
Found mysql_install_db:  "/usr/bin/mysql_install_db" 
Found mysqlcheck:  "/usr/bin/mysqlcheck" 
Database process exited unexpectedly during initial connection!
executable: "/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi"
arguments: ("--defaults-file=/home/tim/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf", "--datadir=/home/tim/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/", "--socket=/tmp/akonadi-tim.p5HYc0/mysql.socket")
stdout: ""
stderr: "2015-12-04 14:51:44 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-12-04 14:51:44 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.25-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) starting as process 28618 ...
"
exit code: 1
process error: "Process operation timed out"
"[
0: akonadiserver() [0x805c67b]
1: akonadiserver() [0x805c929]
2: [0xb7766bbc]
3: [0xb7766be0]
4: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x47) [0xb6e90057]
5: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x149) [0xb6e91699]
6: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_Z17qt_message_output9QtMsgTypePKc+0x124) [0xb74911d4]
7: akonadiserver() [0x805e672]
8: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN9QIODevice5writeEPKcx+0xab) [0xb75394bb]
9: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(+0x1168cf) [0xb754a8cf]
10: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN11QTextStreamD1Ev+0x38) [0xb7553cd8]
11: akonadiserver() [0x80c9c70]
12: akonadiserver() [0x805f277]
13: akonadiserver() [0x8061a49]
14: akonadiserver() [0x812a8b1]
15: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN14QMetaCallEvent13placeMetaCallEP7QObject+0x2a) [0xb75c8b0a]
16: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN7QObject5eventEP6QEvent+0x1b9) [0xb75d0ff9]
17: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN23QCoreApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x5c) [0xb75b65fc]
18: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x4e) [0xb75b665e]
19: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication14notifyInternalEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x8a) [0xb75b640a]
20: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN23QCoreApplicationPrivate16sendPostedEventsEP7QObjectiP11QThreadData+0x211) [0xb75b9f91]
21: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication16sendPostedEventsEP7QObjecti+0x25) [0xb75ba4e5]
22: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(+0x1b44f1) [0xb75e84f1]
23: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x244) [0xb6d44d64]
24: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x47089) [0xb6d45089]
25: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_iteration+0x36) [0xb6d45156]
26: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN20QEventDispatcherGlib13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x73) [0xb75e8653]
27: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN10QEventLoop13processEventsE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x4f) [0xb75b4d8f]
28: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x1ae) [0xb75b511e]
29: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv+0x96) [0xb75bb266]
30: akonadiserver() [0x8056ae4]
31: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xde) [0xb6e7c72e]
32: akonadiserver() [0x8057588]
]
"
ProcessControl: Application 'akonadiserver' returned with exit code 255 (Unknown error)
search paths:  ("/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/sbin", "/bin", "/usr/games", "/usr/local/games", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/libexec", "/usr/libexec", "/opt/mysql/libexec", "/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin", "/opt/mysql/sbin") 
Found mysql_install_db:  "/usr/bin/mysql_install_db" 
Found mysqlcheck:  "/usr/bin/mysqlcheck" 
Database process exited unexpectedly during initial connection!
executable: "/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi"
arguments: ("--defaults-file=/home/tim/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf", "--datadir=/home/tim/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/", "--socket=/tmp/akonadi-tim.p5HYc0/mysql.socket")
stdout: ""
stderr: "2015-12-04 14:51:47 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-12-04 14:51:47 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.25-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) starting as process 28633 ...
"
exit code: 1
process error: "Process operation timed out"
"[
0: akonadiserver() [0x805c67b]
1: akonadiserver() [0x805c929]
2: [0xb775bbbc]
3: [0xb775bbe0]
4: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x47) [0xb6e85057]
5: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x149) [0xb6e86699]
6: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_Z17qt_message_output9QtMsgTypePKc+0x124) [0xb74861d4]
7: akonadiserver() [0x805e672]
8: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN9QIODevice5writeEPKcx+0xab) [0xb752e4bb]
9: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(+0x1168cf) [0xb753f8cf]
10: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN11QTextStreamD1Ev+0x38) [0xb7548cd8]
11: akonadiserver() [0x80c9c70]
12: akonadiserver() [0x805f277]
13: akonadiserver() [0x8061a49]
14: akonadiserver() [0x812a8b1]
15: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN14QMetaCallEvent13placeMetaCallEP7QObject+0x2a) [0xb75bdb0a]
16: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN7QObject5eventEP6QEvent+0x1b9) [0xb75c5ff9]
17: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN23QCoreApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x5c) [0xb75ab5fc]
18: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x4e) [0xb75ab65e]
19: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication14notifyInternalEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x8a) [0xb75ab40a]
20: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN23QCoreApplicationPrivate16sendPostedEventsEP7QObjectiP11QThreadData+0x211) [0xb75aef91]
21: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication16sendPostedEventsEP7QObjecti+0x25) [0xb75af4e5]
22: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(+0x1b44f1) [0xb75dd4f1]
23: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x244) [0xb6d39d64]
24: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x47089) [0xb6d3a089]
25: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_iteration+0x36) [0xb6d3a156]
26: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN20QEventDispatcherGlib13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x73) [0xb75dd653]
27: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN10QEventLoop13processEventsE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x4f) [0xb75a9d8f]
28: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x1ae) [0xb75aa11e]
29: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv+0x96) [0xb75b0266]
30: akonadiserver() [0x8056ae4]
31: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xde) [0xb6e7172e]
32: akonadiserver() [0x8057588]
]
"
ProcessControl: Application 'akonadiserver' returned with exit code 255 (Unknown error)
search paths:  ("/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/sbin", "/bin", "/usr/games", "/usr/local/games", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/libexec", "/usr/libexec", "/opt/mysql/libexec", "/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin", "/opt/mysql/sbin") 
Found mysql_install_db:  "/usr/bin/mysql_install_db" 
Found mysqlcheck:  "/usr/bin/mysqlcheck" 
Database process exited unexpectedly during initial connection!
executable: "/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi"
arguments: ("--defaults-file=/home/tim/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf", "--datadir=/home/tim/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/", "--socket=/tmp/akonadi-tim.p5HYc0/mysql.socket")
stdout: ""
stderr: "2015-12-04 14:51:48 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-12-04 14:51:48 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.25-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) starting as process 28647 ...
"
exit code: 1
process error: "Process operation timed out"
"[
0: akonadiserver() [0x805c67b]
1: akonadiserver() [0x805c929]
2: [0xb7738bbc]
3: [0xb7738be0]
4: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x47) [0xb6e62057]
5: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x149) [0xb6e63699]
6: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_Z17qt_message_output9QtMsgTypePKc+0x124) [0xb74631d4]
7: akonadiserver() [0x805e672]
8: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN9QIODevice5writeEPKcx+0xab) [0xb750b4bb]
9: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(+0x1168cf) [0xb751c8cf]
10: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN11QTextStreamD1Ev+0x38) [0xb7525cd8]
11: akonadiserver() [0x80c9c70]
12: akonadiserver() [0x805f277]
13: akonadiserver() [0x8061a49]
14: akonadiserver() [0x812a8b1]
15: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN14QMetaCallEvent13placeMetaCallEP7QObject+0x2a) [0xb759ab0a]
16: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN7QObject5eventEP6QEvent+0x1b9) [0xb75a2ff9]
17: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN23QCoreApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x5c) [0xb75885fc]
18: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x4e) [0xb758865e]
19: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication14notifyInternalEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x8a) [0xb758840a]
20: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN23QCoreApplicationPrivate16sendPostedEventsEP7QObjectiP11QThreadData+0x211) [0xb758bf91]
21: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication16sendPostedEventsEP7QObjecti+0x25) [0xb758c4e5]
22: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(+0x1b44f1) [0xb75ba4f1]
23: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x244) [0xb6d16d64]
24: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x47089) [0xb6d17089]
25: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_iteration+0x36) [0xb6d17156]
26: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN20QEventDispatcherGlib13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x73) [0xb75ba653]
27: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN10QEventLoop13processEventsE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x4f) [0xb7586d8f]
28: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x1ae) [0xb758711e]
29: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv+0x96) [0xb758d266]
30: akonadiserver() [0x8056ae4]
31: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xde) [0xb6e4e72e]
32: akonadiserver() [0x8057588]
]
"
ProcessControl: Application 'akonadiserver' returned with exit code 255 (Unknown error)
search paths:  ("/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/sbin", "/bin", "/usr/games", "/usr/local/games", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/libexec", "/usr/libexec", "/opt/mysql/libexec", "/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin", "/opt/mysql/sbin") 
Found mysql_install_db:  "/usr/bin/mysql_install_db" 
Found mysqlcheck:  "/usr/bin/mysqlcheck" 
Database process exited unexpectedly during initial connection!
executable: "/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi"
arguments: ("--defaults-file=/home/tim/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf", "--datadir=/home/tim/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/", "--socket=/tmp/akonadi-tim.p5HYc0/mysql.socket")
stdout: ""
stderr: "2015-12-04 14:51:49 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-12-04 14:51:49 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.25-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) starting as process 28661 ...
"
exit code: 1
process error: "Process operation timed out"
"[
0: akonadiserver() [0x805c67b]
1: akonadiserver() [0x805c929]
2: [0xb76f9bbc]
3: [0xb76f9be0]
4: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x47) [0xb6e23057]
5: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x149) [0xb6e24699]
6: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_Z17qt_message_output9QtMsgTypePKc+0x124) [0xb74241d4]
7: akonadiserver() [0x805e672]
8: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN9QIODevice5writeEPKcx+0xab) [0xb74cc4bb]
9: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(+0x1168cf) [0xb74dd8cf]
10: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN11QTextStreamD1Ev+0x38) [0xb74e6cd8]
11: akonadiserver() [0x80c9c70]
12: akonadiserver() [0x805f277]
13: akonadiserver() [0x8061a49]
14: akonadiserver() [0x812a8b1]
15: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN14QMetaCallEvent13placeMetaCallEP7QObject+0x2a) [0xb755bb0a]
16: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN7QObject5eventEP6QEvent+0x1b9) [0xb7563ff9]
17: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN23QCoreApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x5c) [0xb75495fc]
18: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x4e) [0xb754965e]
19: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication14notifyInternalEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x8a) [0xb754940a]
20: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN23QCoreApplicationPrivate16sendPostedEventsEP7QObjectiP11QThreadData+0x211) [0xb754cf91]
21: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication16sendPostedEventsEP7QObjecti+0x25) [0xb754d4e5]
22: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(+0x1b44f1) [0xb757b4f1]
23: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x244) [0xb6cd7d64]
24: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x47089) [0xb6cd8089]
25: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_iteration+0x36) [0xb6cd8156]
26: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN20QEventDispatcherGlib13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x73) [0xb757b653]
27: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN10QEventLoop13processEventsE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x4f) [0xb7547d8f]
28: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x1ae) [0xb754811e]
29: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv+0x96) [0xb754e266]
30: akonadiserver() [0x8056ae4]
31: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xde) [0xb6e0f72e]
32: akonadiserver() [0x8057588]
]
"
ProcessControl: Application 'akonadiserver' returned with exit code 255 (Unknown error)
"akonadiserver" crashed too often and will not be restarted!
```

Any other Info I can supply, I am willing to

Comment: I think the community is working hard to fix this issue. I did not solve it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250761/akonadi-server-does-not-start