# Akonadi server does not start

Tags: akonadi

Akonadi refuses to start.

I tried removing the `~/.local/share/akonadi` folder and running it fresh, and I also tried starting Akonadi from a new user.
As you can see it is not complaining about mysql-files directory however I had it.

I purged `akonadi/*` and reinstalled.
apparmor stop and disabled therefore is not apparmor issue

mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 (Ubuntu)

```
$ akonadictl start  
    Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
    org.kde.pim.akonadicontrol: Service ":1.181" owner changed from "" to ":1.181"
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Starting up the Akonadi Server...
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Found mysql_install_db:  ""
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Found mysqlcheck:  "/usr/bin/mysqlcheck"
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Using mysqld: "/usr/sbin/mysqld"
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: mysqld reports version 8.0.20 (Oracle MySQL)
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Executing: "/usr/sbin/mysqld" "--defaults-file=/home/brad/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf --datadir=/home/brad/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/ --socket=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.socket --pid-file=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.pid"
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: database server stopped unexpectedly
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Database process exited unexpectedly during initial connection!
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: executable: "/usr/sbin/mysqld"
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: arguments: ("--defaults-file=/home/brad/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf", "--datadir=/home/brad/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/", "--socket=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.socket", "--pid-file=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.pid")
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stdout: ""
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stderr: ""
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: exit code: 1
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: process error: "Process operation timed out"
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: terminating connection threads
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: terminating service threads
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stopping db process
    mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
    error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.socket' (2)'
    Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.socket' exists!
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Failed to remove runtime connection config file
    org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Shutting down AkonadiServer...
    org.kde.pim.akonadicontrol: Service ":1.181" owner changed from ":1.181" to ""
    org.kde.pim.akonadicontrol: Application '/usr/bin/akonadiserver' exited normally...
```

Upon 20.10 upgrade reinstalled mysql-server and the output is this:

$ akonadictl start --verbose

```
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Starting up the Akonadi Server...
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Found mysql_install_db:  "/usr/bin/mysql_install_db"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Found mysqlcheck:  "/usr/bin/mysqlcheck"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Using mysqld: "/usr/sbin/mysqld"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: mysqld reports version 10.5.12 (MariaDB)
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Executing: "/usr/sbin/mysqld" "--defaults-file=/home/brad/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf --datadir=/home/brad/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/ --socket=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.socket --pid-file=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.pid"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: database server stopped unexpectedly
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Database process exited unexpectedly during initial connection!
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: executable: "/usr/sbin/mysqld"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: arguments: ("--defaults-file=/home/brad/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf", "--datadir=/home/brad/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/", "--socket=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.socket", "--pid-file=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.pid")
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stdout: ""
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stderr: "2021-09-11 15:01:03 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.5.12-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 10897 ...\n"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: exit code: 1
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: process error: "Unknown error"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: terminating connection threads
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: terminating service threads
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stopping db process
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Shutting down AkonadiServer...
org.kde.pim.akonadicontrol: Application '/usr/bin/akonadiserver' exited normally...
```

UPDATE: this issue was solved by reinstalling mysql

```
brad@zika:~$ akonadictl start -v
akonadictl 5.18.1 (21.08.1)
brad@zika:~$ akonadictl start 
org.kde.pim.akonadictl: Starting Akonadi Server...
org.kde.pim.akonadictl:    done.
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
brad@zika:~$ org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Starting up the Akonadi Server...
akonadi.collectionattributetable                   OK
akonadi.collectionmimetyperelation                 OK
akonadi.collectionpimitemrelation                  OK
akonadi.collectiontable                            OK
akonadi.flagtable                                  OK
akonadi.mimetypetable                              OK
akonadi.parttable                                  OK
akonadi.parttypetable                              OK
akonadi.pimitemflagrelation                        OK
akonadi.pimitemtable                               OK
akonadi.pimitemtagrelation                         OK
akonadi.relationtable                              OK
akonadi.relationtypetable                          OK
akonadi.resourcetable                              OK
akonadi.schemaversiontable                         OK
akonadi.tagattributetable                          OK
akonadi.tagremoteidresourcerelationtable           OK
akonadi.tagtable                                   OK
akonadi.tagtypetable                               OK
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Running DB initializer
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: DB initializer done
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
org.kde.pim.akonadicontrol: Akonadi server is now operational.

brad@zika:~$ akonadictl status 
Akonadi Control: running
Akonadi Server: running
Akonadi Server Search Support: available (Remote Search)
Available Agent Types: No agent types found!
brad@zika:~$ akonadictl stop 
brad@zika:~$ org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Shutting down AkonadiServer...
org.kde.pim.akonadicontrol: Application '/usr/bin/akonadiserver' exited normally...

brad@zika:~$
```

Comment: thank you so much to those who had viewed this topic

Answer (score 0):

When we have issues with the default mysql that comes with KDE, we can have our own MySQL server and ask KDE to store its data there.

Details are here
https://gist.github.com/aldolat/e8066baf8a390e5d5f5ed6e0849ec78c